# Volatiles, memory barriers & cache coherence in .NET?

Tags: .net, caching, volatile

After reading Richter's CLR via C#, some threads on SO and [habr](http://habr.com), and wiki on MSI/MESI/MOESI/etc., I still don't understand:
Why one still need `Thread.MemoryBarrier` or `volatile` if processors already have cache coherence protocols? Doesn't that mean that any read/write operation on cached shared variable invokes synchronization of it's value between caches?
If no, then does `Interlocked` helps to enforce cache coherence?
**EDIT**: The reason of question is that I'm working on application that is intended to work with a bunch of background threads that should safely exit on some flag update, but if I understand correctly, I should surround flag read with `MemoryBarrier`/`Interlocked` statement.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First question, is whether you can assume that such protocols exist and implemented by the hardware or not. Then whether you can assume if the OS implemented that with an advance, efficient way. If any of these two options fail, I then probably the most efficient options are going to be already existing language constructs, that has been revisited many times to make they are correct and efficient.

Comment: @bmolnar Intel & AMD uses MESIF & MOESI respectively, that's pretty enough, since app won't be used on other architectures; talking about OS, Windows is still primary platform for .NET apps, and I guess, they managed the problem. In this case, you say, I have nothing to worry about and just implement the algorithm without `volatile`s, `MemoryBarrier`s and `Interlocked`s?